# Cannot find the dropdown list in page source using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, microsoft-edge

I am doing some web scraping using Selenium.
I was able to find the input box and put the ID numbers there. However, this search box doesn't have a submit button. Once you put the number in, it automatically shows the possible suggestions in the drop down list as shown below.
I could only click on one of the suggestions to go to the detail page of that Shipment ID. I am stuck here because I am not sure what to do after I put the IDs in. I couldn't find any option element in page source and there is no submit button for this search bar. The only thing I can think of is to create action chain to click on the first suggestion it shows.
I am very new to web scraping, any help is appreciated!

[Search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa2t9.jpg)

```
if(driver.current_url == shipments_url):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-select-10-input']").send_keys("7208912992")
else:
    print("url is not right")
```

```html
<div class="NavBar__RightSideElements-sc-xkhgtb-2 xjVyk">
  <div id="globalSearch" class="NavBar__GlobalSearch-sc-7mdmhq-0 lhZoQY">
    <div class="Shipments__GlobalSearchWrapper-sc-1j5srgj-2 hFHGGe">
      <div class="Component__Content-sc-1sjxl0n-0 fuwZlv GlobalSearch__StyledSearch-sc-1vlntt0-0 gAJXfk">
        <div class="Select__SelectWrapper-wqne9l-0 epNycI">
          <div class="css-1pcexqc-container">
            <div class="Control__StyledControlWrapper-sc-1vc2zqo-2 gaWGPF">
              <div class="css-bg1rzq-control">
                <div class="css-i0ddg3">
                  <div class="css-151xaom-placeholder">Search for shipments</div>
                  <div class="css-pu8o5j">
                    <div class="" style="display: inline-block;"><input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="react-select-10-input" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: 0px center; border: 0px; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;">
                      <div
                        style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="css-1wy0on6"><span></span>
                <div class="DropdownIndicator__DropdownIndicatorWrapper-mte9ch-0 gUkWaB"><span color="#626E7A" class="src__IconWrapper-sc-3vtwt3-0 IzvXf" data-type="caret-down"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M8 10l4 4 4-4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#323232" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></span></div>
```

Sorry if I didn't make it clear before. I was trying to input some texts in the search box and select one from the drop down lists. I located the element of the input box as showing below. However, it wouldn't give me any options in page source after I put the texts in the search box.

```html
<div class="" style="display: inline-block;"><input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="react-select-10-input" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: 0px center; border: 0px; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;">
```

After some research, I realized that the dropdown lists are probably loaded from another source and its not worth my time looking more into it. So, I just manually clicked on the first option from the drop down list using ActionChains. My codes are as follows:

```html
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)   
    sea_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-select-10-input']")
    sea_btn.send_keys(str(id))
    sleep(5)
    size = sea_btn.size
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(to_element=sea_btn,xoffset = 0.5*size['width'], yoffset=70).click().perform()
```

Comment: +KEYS.ENTER would work for the input tag. Also please display the autocomplete tags by right clicking and inspecting them when they pop up.

Comment: Would you be able to share the link of the website you're trying to interact with?

Comment: @ShineJ Its a company link, it requires authorizations to log in..

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I tried to click on the inspect button when the suggestions show, but as soon as I hover on the them and right click, the drop down list disappears. The IDs in the search bar will also be cleared. Is there any other ways to check the autocomplete tags? Thank you for helping out.

Comment: It's hard to find what you want with only a little part of the page source. It would be better if you can make a sample page which can reproduce the situation you meet on the website. So that we can have a test and see how to automate it. Besides, you can open F12 devtools to check if there's any difference in the page elements when the dropdown list shows.

Comment: @YuZhou Hello, Yu. Thank you for your advice. There is no difference in page elements when the dropdown list shows. I couldn't inspect any options from the list either since the dropdown list disappears when I right click. I found a way around by using ActionChains to click on the first option I need, and its working fine so far. if I had more time, I will probably look more into it.

Comment: I'm glad that you have found a workaround. You can put the solution into an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one solution, my problem is same the one mentioned above in comments. @YuZhou Hello, Yu. Thank you for your advice. There is no difference in page elements when the dropdown list shows. I couldn't inspect any options from the list either **since the dropdown list disappears when I right click**. I found a way around by using ActionChains to click on the first option I need, and its working fine so far. if I had more time, I will probably look more into it. –
tong wu
Jan 10, 2022 at 7:47
My Solution: (i've used it in testcafe)

1. first click on that dropdown using xpath.
2. if we click on that dropdown it will open dynamic dropdown list, so used the following actions to select that element,
   **await t.hover(xpathSelector("//*[text()='your text']);
   await t.click(xpathSelector("//*[text()='your text']);**
   Note: you can use similar actions in selenium too, i hope that will work.
   if you want to use above solution in testcafe, please see below points:
   by default, testcafe doesn't support xpathselector so there are articales avialable in web which describes how to use xpaths in testcafe.